# Unable to share message in Facebook API 4.0, with error : Error publishing message

Tags: android, facebook

Currently using Facebook 4.0 API, I try to publish message, but I receive the error as following:

> Error: Error publishing message

Looking for help on this issue.

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ShareDialog shareDialog;
private FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareCallback = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Canceled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getHashKey();

    findViewById(R.id.btn_post).setOnClickListener(this);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, shareCallback);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    postStatus();
}

private void postStatus() {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello UTU")
            .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11114/111141352/3551664-iron-man-6800-hd-wallpapers.jpg"))
            .build();

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
}

private void getHashKey() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you specify the required provider to share content in your manifest? You should also try logging the stack trace of the returned FacebookException to see in greater detail what went wrong and where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above is working. Actually, the problem is due to the application configuration settings in Facebook development console. Need to provide the full package name together with the main activity. Thanks anyway.